# Run a specific application in bg on start and being able to stop it

Tags: ubuntu, boot, systemd

On system boot I want to run a chrome driver in background automatically and be able to stop and restart it when I want. I'm on Ubuntu 16, thus I'll use systemd. While I can add `chromedriver &` for `ExecStart`, what should I add to `ExecStop`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start / stop the service from a kind of shell script , you can use `systemctl start/stop/restart/reload your_service.service` or `systemctl enable/disable your_service.service` if you want to manipulate services that are getting load during boot.

If you want to make a custome .service file, then ExecStop, ExecStopPre and ExecStopPost can be used (see [systemd man pages](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=systemd.service).)

I have seen ExecStop commands that just raise a service stop, or that kill something, or calling a shell script.

I don't know which method will work better for you... But maybe you can google about chromedriver

Examples:

```
/lib/systemd/system/vboxadd.service
.....................
ExecStart=/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.8/init/vboxadd start
ExecStop=/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.8/init/vboxadd stop

Another Service found somewhere
..........................................
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=${script} start
ExecStop=${script} stop

/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service
..........
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore
ExecStop=-/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa store

/lib/systemd/system/systemd-random-seed.service
..............
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed load
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed save

Chromedriver & Selenium Server
...................................
ExecStart=/bin/java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/var/www/selenium/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=/home/selenium/chrome.log -Dselenium.LOGGER=/home/selenium/selenium.log -jar /var/www/selenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
ExecStop=kill `cat /var/spool/selenium/pid/master.pid`
```